# How to write the contents of several inputs into one array?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way to use one handler for input? Let's say I have 10 inputs, and at the moment each of them changes, their contents need to be written in one state, how can I do this? To not use 10 states

```js
 const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState([]);
  
  const onHandleInput = e => {
setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  <label>Sex:</label>
  <select onChange={onHandleInput}>
    <option>Info</option>
  </select>

    <label>First name:</label>
  <input type="text" onChange={onHandleInput} />
  
    <label>Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" onChange={onHandleInput} />
  
    <label>E-mail:</label>
  <input type="text" onChange={onHandleInput} />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code sandbox example ,i did with only two fields ,but it will work for multiple too,just give ids to your fields

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-driscoll-n7v0d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name attribute on the input fields to differentiate between them. The name attribute is then available with `e.target.name` inside of your `onHandleInput` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the index when calling the onHandleInput method like this:

```
<input type="text" onChange={e=>  onHandleInput(e,0)} />
<input type="text" onChange={e=>  onHandleInput(e,1)} />
```

...etc

And then just create a temporary array to change the correct index like this:

```
const onHandleInput = (e, index) => {
  const tempArr = [...inputValue];
  tempArr[index] = e.target.value;
  setInputValue(tempArr);
  console.log(tempArr);
};
```

Comment: this is a way ,if you give id to your input fields ,it will be a cleaner way ,check my code above once

Comment: @warmachine yes and it would work if you have only one instance of the component on your page but if you have more than one you have a problem with your ids because id should be a unique value

Comment: just like you add numbers differently ,ids can be different too and ,if you use the same logic in different component ,it does not matter if your id  in component is same as the id in other component,the variables you are creating is only component scope ,unless you redux ,then it can cause problem,but still you can differentiate based on your container